# Not able to send mail from liferay hook

Tags: email, liferay, hook, sendmail

I am trying to send email from a hook I have using both MailEngine and MailServiceUtil, but I have not yet been able to send it. My code is as below :

```
InternetAddress from=null;
InternetAddress to=null;
try {
 from = new  InternetAddress("test@test.com", "Admin admin");
 to = new InternetAddress(newUser.getEmailAddress(), newUser.getFirstName());
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
} 
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

mailMessage.setFrom(from);
mailMessage.setTo(to);

mailMessage.setBody(body); 
mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
MailServiceUtil.sendEmail(mailMessage);
```

In this I am getting the following error,

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.liferay.portal.kernel.mail.MailMessage.setFrom(Ljavax/mail/internet/InternetAddress;)V" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, com/lftechnology/sbworkbench/hooks/createaccount/CustomCreateAccountAction, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, com/liferay/portal/kernel/mail/MailMessage, have different Class objects for the type javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress used in the signature
```

I found a mail.jar file in my liferay installation but I am not able to use it. I tried importing javax.mail in my pom file with artifactid com.sun but still get this error. Does anybody here know what the problem is ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean: "I found a mail.jar file in my liferay installation but I am not able to use it"? It looks like you have issues with the version of javax.mail (or Java alltogether). If you're using Java 7, try switching back to Java 6.

Comment: I saw a mail.jar file in tomcat's lib/ext, and I thought of using the same, but since I have a maven hook, I could not directly call it. I added a content to pom.xml in my hook project and added the scope as provided, but still got the same error, I checked the version of mail.jar by extracting it and using the same version in pom, but I could not get it to work. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My best guess is that you have multiple versions of mail.jar (or the various other incarnations that contain the same code) on your classpath. You said, you have found mail.jar in tomcat - I guess it's also contained in your webapplication's WEB-INF/lib: Remove it from there, your webapp must use the one from tomcat's global classpath.

You can configure the dependency in Maven as "provided", so that Maven knows that you will depend on that code, but not deploy it with your application

Bringing in your comment: Don't just "redeploy", but undeploy (delete the webapplication) because otherwise tomcat might keep your libraries that you previously provided. Thus you wouldn't copy them again, but they'd still be there.

Comment: I did that as well, changed the scope to "provided" added artifact id "javax.mail" version 1.4, what I was thinking was if the version is not correct, But i extracted the mail.jar file in my tomcat and it does say version 1.4, so I am completely stuck there.

Comment: mail.jar is also available as several separate jars, e.g. mailapi.jar+imap.jar+others - maybe this is where you get multiple versions if these are also around?

Comment: Nope, none of them are present.

Comment: Also, how do I add the dependency in Maven, but deploy the application  without that dependency ?

Comment: check the "provided" dependency scope http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html. When just debugging this, manually dig through what's deployed in your tomcat/lib directory and your webapp's WEB-INF/lib directory. There's no harm to manually delete and restart for testing, fix the build process later. I don't have any other clue than duplicate classes on the classpath, but over the distance I can not help searching for them - sorry, I'm out

Comment: got my mistake, I deployed it once without adding the "provided" dependency, and the mail.jar file was not deleted automatically even though I had put the scope in pom as "provided". I deleted the project from tomcat webapp and redeployed it with the dependency set as "provided" and it worked fine, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to remove mail.jar file from the WEB-INF of my deployed project, and deploying again with the dependency set to provided did not delete the file automatically.

So I removed the project from the webapp page and redeployed the project. And thus it worked.